# Difference between conditional probability and union

Tags: probability

Given the following example:

A researcher examines the medical records of a group of 1000 men who died
in 1989 and discovers that 200 of the men died from causes related to lung disease.
Moreover, 300 of the 1000 men had at least one parent who suffered from lung disease,
and, of these 300 men, 100 died from causes related to lung disease.

Calculate the probability that a man randomly selected from this group died of causes related to lung disease, given that neither of his parents suffered from lung disease.

Now, given

> of these 300 men, 100 died from causes related to lung disease

$P(M) = men\ who\ died\ in\ 1989 $ and

$P(L) = died\ from\ causes\ related\ to\ lung\ disease$

My question is: if only based on the quote, should i set the equation as $P(L|M)$ or $P(L \cap M)$?

Comment: What question are you trying to address?  You seem to have forgotten to include that.

Comment: @ edited, please let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Thanks.  What I don't understand is what you mean by "set the equation."  Why not just look at counts of the relevant groups?  Find how many men have no parent suffering from lung disease; find how many of them died of a cause related to lung disease, and divide one by the other.

Comment: @whuber True, but i am confuse with conditional probability and union. Like I understand their meaning, but if say, the question states "of these 300 men, 100 died from causes related to lung disease", should that be conditional probability or union

Comment: You ask about " ... and union" but then you use the symbol for **intersection**. Could you clarify and edit to correct?